# Eagerly evaluating all predicate calls in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Reading the [SWI-Prolog documentation on meta-predicates](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=metapred), I initially assumed that `call(f, ...)` is equivalent to `f(...)`, where `f` is some predicate. But I observe that the behavior of the two actually diverge in certain cases. For instance, suppose a knowledge base includes the clause `f(g(x))`.  Then the query `call(f, g(x))` succeeds, whereas `f(call(g, x))` does not. This is problematic, because I sometimes need to use clauses whose bodies include nested predicate calls. I'd like Prolog to evaluate all predicate calls eagerly (I wonder if this is the right word?), such that the query `f(call(g, x))` reduces to `f(g(x))` before unification begins, and succeeds. Is this possible?

Comment: Note that Prolog has relations, not functions.  In `f(call(g,x))`, you have a goal for predicate `f/1` with a single argument which is the **term** `call(g,x)`. So there is no way to have arguments "evaluate". You might do this is certain contexts, but I would rather suggest that you first get used to Prolog.

Comment: I see. I guess I was trying to solve a typical XY problem here. I posted [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40444453/distributivity-check-in-prolog) about my initial motivation for trying to do this.