# Distributivity check in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Suppose I have an equivalence relation `eq`, and multiple binary operators `o_1, o_2, ... o_n`. I want to find out which operations distribute over others. Assuming that I have a knowledge base that can determine whether two expressions are equivalent, a simple solution is to just enter all possible queries :

(for left-distributivity)

```
?- eq(o_1(Z,o_1(X,Y)),o_1(o_1(Z,X),o_1(Z,Y))). 
?- eq(o_1(Z,o_2(X,Y)),o_2(o_1(Z,X),o_1(Z,Y))). 
?- eq(o_1(Z,o_3(X,Y)),o_3(o_1(Z,X),o_1(Z,Y))). 

...

?- eq(o_2(Z,o_2(X,Y)),o_2(o_2(Z,X),o_2(Z,Y))). 
?- eq(o_2(Z,o_3(X,Y)),o_3(o_2(Z,X),o_2(Z,Y))). 

...

?- eq(o_n(Z,o_n(X,Y)),o_n(o_n(Z,X),o_n(Z,Y))).
```

but there must be better ways to do this. For starters, I'd like to define a predicate `left_dist` such that `left_dist(o_m,o_k)` would generate the corresponding query for me. I initially thought I'd do this by using `call`, as in

```
left_dist(O_m,O_k) :-
   eq(call(O_m,Z,call(O_k,X,Y)),call(O_k,call(O_m,Z,X),call(O_m,Z,Y))).
```

but the nested calls do not work for reasons outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443755/eagerly-evaluating-all-predicate-calls-in-prolog), and I guess it's not a good way to approach Prolog programming either.

So the question is : how can I define `left_dist`, or otherwise simplify the queries above, in Prolog?

Comment: You will need some domain about which you make such statements!

Comment: What is the intuition behind `O_m` and `O_k`? Why `k`? `m` means multiplication, and `k` means what?

Comment: They're just labels such that 1 ≤ k ≤ n and 1 ≤ m ≤ n. I.e., `o_m` and `o_k` can be any of the binary operators mentioned in the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Left distributivity means that for all `x,y,z`:  `x*(y+z)=(x*y)+(x*z)`

Now you do not mention concrete domains, so I assume that all relations know them already.  This assumes that `Add_3` and `Mult_3` always terminate.

```
not_left_dist(Mult_3, Add_3) :-
   call(Add_3, Y, Z, YZ),
   call(Mult_3, X, YZ, LHS),
   call(Mult_3, X, Y, XY),
   call(Mult_3, X, Z, XZ),
   call(Add_3, XY, XZ, RHS),
   neq(LHS, RHS).

left_dist(Mult_3, Add_3) :-
   iwhen(ground(Mult_3+Add_3), \+ not_left_dist(Mult_3, Add_3) ).
```

This uses [`iwhen/2`](/a/40449516/772868).